# Parsing XML file with many children and grandchildren

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am very new to python. I have this very large xml file and I want to extract some data from it. Here is an excerpt:

```
<program>
    <id>38e072a7-8fc9-4f9a-8eac-3957905c0002</id>
    <programID>3853</programID>
    <orchestra>New York Philharmonic</orchestra>
    <season>1842-43</season>
    <concertInfo>
        <eventType>Subscription Season</eventType>
        <Location>Manhattan, NY</Location>
        <Venue>Apollo Rooms</Venue>
        <Date>1842-12-07T05:00:00Z</Date>
        <Time>8:00PM</Time>
    </concertInfo>
    <worksInfo>
        <work ID="52446*">
            <composerName>Beethoven,  Ludwig  van</composerName>
            <workTitle>SYMPHONY NO. 5 IN C MINOR, OP.67</workTitle>
            <conductorName>Hill, Ureli Corelli</conductorName>
        </work>
        <work ID="8834*4">
            <composerName>Weber,  Carl  Maria Von</composerName>
            <workTitle>OBERON</workTitle>
            <movement>"Ozean, du Ungeheuer" (Ocean, thou mighty monster), Reiza (Scene and Aria), Act II</movement>
            <conductorName>Timm, Henry C.</conductorName>
            <soloists>
                <soloist>
                    <soloistName>Otto, Antoinette</soloistName>
                    <soloistInstrument>Soprano</soloistInstrument>
                    <soloistRoles>S</soloistRoles>
                </soloist>
            </soloists>
        </work>
        <work ID="3642*">
            <composerName>Hummel,  Johann</composerName>
            <workTitle>QUINTET, PIANO, D MINOR, OP. 74</workTitle>
            <soloists>
                <soloist>
                    <soloistName>Scharfenberg, William</soloistName>
                    <soloistInstrument>Piano</soloistInstrument>
                    <soloistRoles>A</soloistRoles>
                </soloist>
                <soloist>
                    <soloistName>Hill, Ureli Corelli</soloistName>
                    <soloistInstrument>Violin</soloistInstrument>
                    <soloistRoles>A</soloistRoles>
                </soloist>
                <soloist>
                    <soloistName>Derwort, G. H.</soloistName>
                    <soloistInstrument>Viola</soloistInstrument>
                    <soloistRoles>A</soloistRoles>
                </soloist>
                <soloist>
                    <soloistName>Boucher, Alfred</soloistName>
                    <soloistInstrument>Cello</soloistInstrument>
                    <soloistRoles>A</soloistRoles>
                </soloist>
                <soloist>
                    <soloistName>Rosier, F. W.</soloistName>
                    <soloistInstrument>Contrabass</soloistInstrument>
                    <soloistRoles>A</soloistRoles>
                </soloist>
            </soloists>
        </work>
        <work ID="0*">
            <interval>Intermission</interval>
        </work>
        <work ID="8834*3">
            <composerName>Weber,  Carl  Maria Von</composerName>
            <workTitle>OBERON</workTitle>
            <movement>Overture</movement>
            <conductorName>Etienne, Denis G.</conductorName>
        </work>
        <work ID="8835*1">
            <composerName>Rossini,  Gioachino</composerName>
            <workTitle>ARMIDA</workTitle>
            <movement>Duet</movement>
            <conductorName>Timm, Henry C.</conductorName>
            <soloists>
                <soloist>
                    <soloistName>Otto, Antoinette</soloistName>
                    <soloistInstrument>Soprano</soloistInstrument>
                    <soloistRoles>S</soloistRoles>
                </soloist>
                <soloist>
                    <soloistName>Horn, Charles Edward</soloistName>
                    <soloistInstrument>Tenor</soloistInstrument>
                    <soloistRoles>S</soloistRoles>
                </soloist>
            </soloists>
        </work>
        <work ID="8837*6">
            <composerName>Beethoven,  Ludwig  van</composerName>
            <workTitle>FIDELIO, OP. 72</workTitle>
            <movement>"In Des Lebens Fruhlingstagen...O spur ich nicht linde," Florestan (aria)</movement>
            <conductorName>Timm, Henry C.</conductorName>
            <soloists>
                <soloist>
                    <soloistName>Horn, Charles Edward</soloistName>
                    <soloistInstrument>Tenor</soloistInstrument>
                    <soloistRoles>S</soloistRoles>
                </soloist>
            </soloists>
        </work>
        <work ID="8336*4">
            <composerName>Mozart,  Wolfgang  Amadeus</composerName>
            <workTitle>ABDUCTION FROM THE SERAGLIO,THE, K.384</workTitle>
            <movement>"Ach Ich liebte," Konstanze (aria)</movement>
            <conductorName>Timm, Henry C.</conductorName>
            <soloists>
                <soloist>
                    <soloistName>Otto, Antoinette</soloistName>
                    <soloistInstrument>Soprano</soloistInstrument>
                    <soloistRoles>S</soloistRoles>
                </soloist>
            </soloists>
        </work>
        <work ID="5543*">
            <composerName>Kalliwoda,  Johann  W.</composerName>
            <workTitle>OVERTURE NO. 1, D MINOR, OP. 38</workTitle>
            <conductorName>Timm, Henry C.</conductorName>
        </work>
    </worksInfo>
</program>
<program>
```

What I would like to do is extract the following pieces of information: programID, orchestra, season, eventType, work ID, soloistName, solositInstrument, soloistRole

Here is the code I am using:

```
import csv
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
tree = ET.iterparse('complete.xml.txt')
#root = tree.getroot()


for program in root.iter('program'):
  ID = program.findtext('id')
  programID = program.findtext('programID')
  orchestra = program.findtext('orchestra')
  season = program.findtext('season')

  for concert in program.findall('concertInfo'):
    event = concert.findtext('eventType')

    for worksInfo in program.findall('worksInfo'):
        for work in worksInfo.iter('work'): 
            workid = work.get('ID')
            for soloists in work.iter('soloists'):
                for soloist in soloists.iter('soloist'):
                    soloname = soloist.findtext('soloistName')
                    soloinstrument =                                                             `soloist.findtext('soloistInstrument')`  
                    solorole = soloist.findtext('soloistRoles')
                    #print(soloname, soloinstrument, solorole)
            #print(workid)
    #print(event)              
#print(programID , " , " , orchestra , " , " , season)
with open("nyphil.txt","a") as nyphil:
    nyphilwriter = csv.writer(nyphil)
    nyphilwriter.writerow([programID, orchestra, season, event, workid,    `soloname.encode('utf-8'), soloinstrument, solorole])
nyphil.close()
```

When I run this code I only get the last soloistName and soloistInstrumet. The outcome that I have in mind is sort of like a repeated observations for each program. So I'd have something like:

13918, New York Philharmonic, 1842-43, Subscription Season, 52446*,  Otto, Antoinette, Soprano, S

13918,...., 3642*, Scharfenberg, William , Piano, A

13918,...., 3642*, Hill, Ureli Corelli , Violin, A

and so on until the last work ID:

13918,...., 8336*4 , Otto, Antoinette, Soprano, S

What I am getting is only the last work:

13918, New York Philharmonic, 1842-43, Subscription Season, 8336*,  Otto, Antoinette, Soprano, S

In the file there are over 15,000 programs like the example I posted. I want to parse all of them and extract the information I mentioned above. I am not entirely sure how to go about doing this, I've scoured the internet for a way to do this, but everything I tried just doesn't work!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that you misunderstand the way loops work. Specifically, the values only change while you're in the loop:

```
for x in range(10):
    pass

print(x) # prints 9
```

vs

```
for x in range(10):
    print(x)
```

Those are two different things. You're doing the former. What you need to do is something like this:

```
with open('nyphil.txt', 'w') as f:
    nyphilwriter = csv.writer(f)        
    for program in root.iter('program'):
        id_ = program.findtext('id')
        program_id = program.findtext('programID')
        orchestra = program.findtext('orchestra')
        season = program.findtext('season')
        for concert in program.findall('concertInfo'):
            event = concert.findtext('eventType')
        for info in program.findall('worksInfo'):
            for work in info.iter('work'):
                work_id = work.get('ID')
                for soloists in work.iter('soloists'):
                    for soloist in soloists.iter('soloist'):
                        # Change this line to whatever you want to write out
                        nyphilwriter.writerow([id, program_id, orchestra, season, event, work_id, soloist.findtext('soloistName')])
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This is exactly what I needed. I am very new to all of this, and I was indeed super confused by how loops actually work. This was a tremendous help though, thanks!!

Comment: If this answer is the one that best solves your problem, you should mark it accepted by pressing the checkmark over to the left there `<-----`. If you find it (and any other answers) particularly helpful, you can also upvote them with the triangle above the number.

Comment: Hi Wayne, I upvoted it but I have less than 15 reputation so it is not recorded :/ but your answer was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The 13918 does not appear in your data. Leaving that aside, here's what I wrote, which appears to process your data successfully.

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('test.xml')
programs = tree.xpath('.//program')

for program in programs:
    programID, orchestra, season = [program.xpath(_)[0].text for _ in ['programID', 'orchestra', 'season']]
    print (programID, orchestra, season)
    works = program.xpath('worksInfo/work')
    for work in works:
        workID = work.attrib['ID']
        soloistItems = work.xpath('soloists/soloist')
        for soloistItem in soloistItems:
            print (workID, soloistItem.find('soloistName').text, soloistItem.find('soloistInstrument').text, soloistItem.find('soloistRoles').text)
```

The script produces the following output.

```
3853 New York Philharmonic 1842-43
8834*4 Otto, Antoinette Soprano S
3642* Scharfenberg, William Piano A
3642* Hill, Ureli Corelli Violin A
3642* Derwort, G. H. Viola A
3642* Boucher, Alfred Cello A
3642* Rosier, F. W. Contrabass A
8835*1 Otto, Antoinette Soprano S
8835*1 Horn, Charles Edward Tenor S
8837*6 Horn, Charles Edward Tenor S
8336*4 Otto, Antoinette Soprano S
```

One other thing to note: I put a  tag at the beginning of your XML and a  at the end since the real data would contain multiple  elements.